# How can I prevent ASP.NET from adding to the inline styles?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, coding-style, asp.net-2.0

I have an element that I'm trying to style:

```
<tr runat="server" id="row" >
...
</tr>
```

And I set the style programmatically:

```
row.Attributes("style") = "background: #cccccc;"
```

I get this output:

```
<tr id="SearchResults_myRepeaterPlain_ctl04_row" style="background: rgb(204, 204, 204) none repeat scroll 0% 0%; -moz-background-clip: border; -moz-background-origin: padding; -moz-background-inline-policy: continuous;">
```

Where is all that additional style information coming from, and How can I stop it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My hunch is because you're only using background.  It's adding all the other values for background.  Try using background-color:

Comment: +1, see the documentation for the CSS background property:  http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_background.asp.

Comment: Switching to background-color did, in fact, fix the issue.